# I am having trouble on installing pip for windows 7

Tags: python, windows, pip

I have tried and tried to install pip but I cannot seem to install it. I have python 3.7 which is supposed to have pip preinstalled. But I have tried all the commands in the command prompt but it always says pip is not a recognized file or directory. So can someone please help try and find a way to download or see if I have pip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to check if you have `pip` installed or not write `pip` in terminal. To install pip you can do -

1. Download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) to a folder on your computer.
2. Open a command prompt and navigate to the folder containing get-pip.py.
3. Run the following command:

   `python get-pip.py`
4. Pip is now installed!

Hope this will help.

Comment: HI so i did exatly what you told me and i keep getting an error meseege saying no such file or directory do you have any ideas of how i might fix this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you download the file and checking the right directory?

Comment: Yeah I did but I finally got it working and thank you for all the help.